# Spring Integration Service Activator handler business logic

Tags: java-8, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-aws

I am currently new to Spring Integration.
Basically trying to poll onto multiple file locations asynchronously with Java Spring integration DSL. I am required to get the file name and perform some operations with filename and push the file to S3 finally, my question is can these tasks of performing operations with file be performed in the task executor or the service activator handler . I am not sure which is the right place.

```
@Autowired
private AWSFileManager awsFileManager;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundChannelFlow(@Value("${file.poller.delay}") long delay,
@Value("${file.poller.messages}") int maxMsgsPerPoll,
TaskExecutor taskExecutor, MessageSource<File> fileSource) 
{
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fileSource,
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(delay)
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMsgsPerPoll)))
            .handle("AWSFileManager", "fileUpload")
            .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.inboundChannel)
            .get();
}

@Bean
TaskExecutor taskExecutor(@Value("${file.poller.thread.pool.size}") int poolSize) {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    //Runnable task1 = () -> {this.methodsamp();};
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(poolSize);

    //taskExecutor.execute(task1);
    return taskExecutor;
}
@Async
public void methodsamp()
{
    try
    {
        awsFileManager.fileUpload();
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

I have attached the sample code here.
Also is there a way I could retrieve the filename of the files in the channel as I need to pass this as parameter to the fileUpload method.
Please advise.

Comment: Please, don't ask too much questions per one SO thread.

Comment: Ya sure.. will follow it next time. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. The `TaskExecutor` is for the thread context in the flow. The Service Activator (`.handle()`) is exactly for your business logic method. This one can be performed on a thread from the executor. And you really use them in your `IntegrationFlow` correctly.

The `FileReadingMessageSource` produces message with the `java.io.File` as a `payload`. So, that is the way to get a file name - just from `File.getName()`!

Comment: Thank you so much Artem. I got it but the handler takes just the bean name and method name which are both strings. How would I specify the parameter of filename to them?

Comment: Why would you care about that? I suppose you definitely need a `File` object to send it to the AWS S3. So, you should expect in your `fileUpload()` something what is a `poyload` of the message which is received by the `.handle()`.

Comment: I suggest you to read Books on the matter or at least Spring Integration Reference Manual. The `fileReadingMessageSource‌​` produces messages with files as their payloads. They are sent to the channel. The `.handle()` subscribes to that channel and call your service method and provide appropriate values for arguments of the method. You should make your service method as `fileUpload(File fileToUpload)` and the `payload` of incoming message will be passed to this argument.

Comment: I am unable to get the handlers run serially. I have something like this: `.handle("awsFileManager", "fileUpload").handle("FileWriterMessageHandler")` they don't seem to run one after the other, the file writer message handler is called before the file upload method

Comment: That's different question. And you need to keep in mind that the next `.handle()` is based on the result of the previous. And I am even surprised that it is called at all, since I don't see how your `fileUpload()` returns anything.

Comment: The fileUpload just returns a boolean value of true of false based on whether file upload was successful or not. Is it supposed to return a standard value ?

Comment: Please, start a new SO question. This is against rules to discuss not related topic.

Comment: Sorry for the questions in the comments @Artem . I have created one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560693/service-activator-handlers-not-running-serially